# How to get all collection names in MongoDb using C++

Tags: c++, mongodb, driver

There is a great [MongoDb C++ Driver](http://api.mongodb.org/cxx/legacy-1.0.0/annotated.html). The only thing that makes it hard for newbies like me to use it - is the lack of teeny-weeny examples. For instance, I know there is a method called `getCollectionNames`, but I'm not sure how to use it. In `Python` I would do it like this:

```
db = MongoClient(host, port)[db_name]
colls = db.collection_names()
```

and I'm done. But I don't feel so comfortable with `C++` and can not figure out myself how to convert raw function declarations in documentation to some working code.

So, this is what I've done by now and see that it works:

```
ConnectionString cs = ConnectionString::parse(uri, errmsg);
DBClientBase * conn(cs.connect(errmsg));
```

Now I want to make one step further and get all collection names. Please, give some advice.

**EDIT**

Well, I found a method somewhere in `dbclientinterface.h` called `getCollectionNames`. It is defined like so:

```
std::list<std::string> getCollectionNames( const std::string& db,
                                           const BSON& filter = BSONObj())
```

But I find this sole declaration without any informative hints completely useless. It is just a sum of letters and no more.

**EDIT**

I found a solution and I will post it below.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
std::string uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb";
std::string errmsg;
ConnectionString cs = ConnectionString::parse(uri, errmsg);
DBClientBase * conn(cs.connect(errmsg));
std::list<std::string> colls = conn->getCollectionNames("mydb");
for(std::list<std::string>::iterator it = colls.begin();it != colls.end();++it){
     do_something(*it);
}
```